# What is the largest number n such that realmax+n does not generate an overflow?

Tags: octave

The problem is the following: What is the largest number `n` such that `realmax+n` does not generate an overflow?

I tried using the following value for `n`, but none of them worked.

```
n = eps('double');
disp(n);
realmax + n
```

Comment: The answer is 0.  That is, after all, the very definition of `realmax`.  There are no larger values.

Comment: @TimRoberts But when I put realmax+1, it does not show me overflow. Even for much larger numbers, it does not show overflow.

Comment: `eps(realmax)` is the smallest number to add to produce an overflow. So any value smaller than that will not cause an overflow.